# HTML/CSS - How do I fill background of region to left of div that shrinks on zoom out?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Scenario**

I want to create a spotlight in css that fixes position relative to the parent div on any user zoom level.

I want to "fill" the entire screen with the shadow but I can not get the spotlight to respond to zoom when I apply the shadow to the entire page.

**Problem**

The left portion in my jsfiddle container (account-settings-confirm-container-left-fill) does not show a shadow.

**What I have done so far..**

```
<div class="container account-settings-confirm-container-left-fill"> </div>
  <div class="container account-settings-confirm-container">
 <div class="spotlight"></div>
  <div class="account-settings-confirm">
        <div class="row account-settings-confirm-banner extend-full">
          </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Accompanying jsfiddle I created.

**jsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/10nmL3vv/

**Result (Full Screen)**

https://jsfiddle.net/10nmL3vv/embedded/result/

How do I modify my code to make the shadow take up the entire page?

EDIT

I tried to make this modification to the left fill to no avail.

```
.account-settings-confirm-container-left-fill{
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

Comment: I used the following codepen to create my spotlight (My jsfiddle is my entire code)
https://codepen.io/tjacobdesign/pen/gulHf

Comment: Fill left with another div, and set width and length to auto.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I made the modifications in my edit but I did not get a filled shadow.  If I try width:100% it overlaps my other shadow doubling the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap `container` classes have max-width values of

none, 750px, 970px, 1170px .. depending on the screen size.

**Refer** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

You can change the `.container` class to `.container-fluid`

and remove

`margin-left: -55px;` from `.spotlight` element. Should cover it.

Here is a fork. [Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3byy5rb5/1/)

**Edit:** You could target the pseudo `:before` of the element `.spotlight` and add the following

```
.spotlight:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;   
  left: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
}
```

Just note that it will be absolute positioned to `html`. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10nmL3vv/2/)

Comment: I did attempt to modify container to container-fluid but he spotlight and the entire page is pulled apart when I zoom out as with container-fluid.  Is there any way I can zoom out and keep the spotlight in the same relative location as the place where it is zoomed out rather than stay a fixed position on the screen?

Comment: I need  a way to fill the white space to the left of spotlight.  Can this be done with css only?

Comment: I think so. fixed to specs. check the post. Hopefully that solves it.